# C# WPF ListView ItemsSource - Setting Text & Picture

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, visual-studio-2013

Currently in my List View I am setting text, pictures & text color with the following code which looks like this - http://oi61.tinypic.com/nzggls.jpg

[image]

```
foreach (Mods modname in gameMods)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(ArmA3PATH, "@" + modname.ModString)))
    {
        lstMods.Items.Add(new listViewItem
                (
                    modname.ModName.ToString(),
                    Path.Combine(dir, modname.ModLink),
                    new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green)
                )
            );
    }
    else
    {
        lstMods.Items.Add(new listViewItem
                (
                    modname.ModName.ToString(),
                    Path.Combine(dir, modname.ModLink),
                    new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red)
                )
          );
    }
}
```

Both classes are as follows, where gameMods is simply a List created with Mods, List

```
public class listViewItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImagePic { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public listViewItem(string text, string image, System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        Text = text;
        ImagePic = image;
        BackgroundColor = color;
    }
}

public class Mods
{
    public string ModName { get; set; }
    public string ModVersion { get; set; }
    public string ModLink { get; set; }
    public string ModString { get; set; }
    public string ModLogo { get; set; }

    public Mods(string modName, string modVersion, string modLink, string modString, string modLogo)
    {
        this.ModName = modName;
        this.ModVersion = modVersion;
        this.ModLink = modLink;
        this.ModString = modString;
        this.ModLogo = modLogo;
    }
}
```

The XAML markup for the above code is

```
<ListView x:Name="lstMods">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePic}" Width="80" Height="80" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding BackgroundColor}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
            ItemWidth="248"
            MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Now, this works just fine; but I can't use SelectionChanged & SelectedItem like this to grab values, so what way would I be able to use ItemsSource on the ListView and still add images/text to the ListView blocks?

Currently, the ItemsSource when doing lstMods.ItemsSource = gameMods, looks like this http://oi59.tinypic.com/dwi0m.jpg

[image]

I know that's because there are no bound text values, but I'm not quite sure where to add these values for Item Sourcing.

Comment: You're using WPF man! Just bind to SelectedItem as a property, as long as you implement INotifyPropertyChanged you'll be able to subscribe to changes. If you create an ObservableCollection<Mods> (the same way you declare a List in .Net) you can add and remove mods and the change will be reflected visually on the ListView. Create a single Mod property for your currently selected one.

Comment: It's not changes I want to reference, they're all handled via an XML file anyway for the server admins to update or modify; it's more populating the list via ItemsSource to attach the gameList information to that ListView item so you could retrieve information about the item you select.

Going to look at some MSDN articles and see what I can do with it for SelectedItem or ItemsSource & SelectionChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few minutes of looking at this today all I done was the following which done as I was looking for originally

```
rivate void lstMods_DblClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selection = lstMods.SelectedItem;
    var mod = selection as listViewItem;

    MessageBox.Show(mod.LinkUrl);
}

public class listViewItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImagePic { get; set; }
    public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public listViewItem(string text, string image, System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush color, string modlink)
    {
        Text = text;
        ImagePic = image;
        BackgroundColor = color;
        LinkUrl = modlink;
    }
}

foreach (Mods modname in gameMods)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(ArmA3PATH, "@" + modname.ModString)))
    {
        lstMods.Items.Add(new listViewItem
                (
                    modname.ModName.ToString(),
                    Path.Combine(dir, modname.ModLink),
                    new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green),
                    modname.ModLink.ToString()
                )
            );
    }
    else
    {
        lstMods.Items.Add(new listViewItem
                (
                    modname.ModName.ToString(),
                    Path.Combine(dir, modname.ModLink),
                    new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red),
                    modname.ModLink.ToString()
                )
          );
    }
}
```

And the XAML being

```
<ListView x:Name="lstMods" MouseDoubleClick="lstMods_DblClick">
```

So really, the only change I made was that originally I was referring to the SelectionChanged as the "Mods" class when it should have been the listViewItem class.

Comment: Plus, I know I'm using the wrong class here of Selection Changed, this has now been changed in my code to MouseDoubleClick

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielLane mentioned, in WPF, we tend to data bind collections to `ItemsControl`s in the UI. In your case, you should have an `Items` (or similarly named) property that holds your `listViewItem` instances:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstMods" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

Then you'd change your code to something similar to below:

```
Items.Add(new listViewItem
    (
        modname.ModName.ToString(),
        Path.Combine(dir, modname.ModLink),
        new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green)
    )
);
```

To get this to work correctly, you'd need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the class with the `Items` property. Typically, we'd add another property of type `listViewItem` that represents the selected item in the collection:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

Now whenever a new item is selected in the `GridView`, the `YourSelectedItem` property setter will get called:

```
private listViewItem yourSelectedItem;
public listViewItem YourSelectedItem
{ 
    get { return yourSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        yourSelectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("YourSelectedItem");
        // The selected item changed so you can do something with the new item here
     }
}
```

Please refer to the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help.